# Django charts.js of database column?

Tags: django

I have a model database in this format

```
sno Date    Premium Count   Time    Date_time   Close   
None    Oct. 13, 2021   None    2   2:22 p.m.   38735   
None    Oct. 13, 2021   None    2   2:23 p.m.   38727   
None    Oct. 13, 2021   None    2   2:24 p.m.   38739   
None    Oct. 13, 2021   None    2   2:25 p.m.   38750   
None    Oct. 13, 2021   None    2   2:26 p.m.   38730   
None    Oct. 13, 2021   None    2   2:27 p.m.   38723
```

I want to make a simple bar chart of `'Close'` column in the database. I have tried using some manual random values in chart.js code which I have done successfully, but how do I take the database field 'Close' , converting it into a list and plot a chart from it?